# How do I bind value of mat-slider to mat-input in angular without ngmodel using dynamic variable name?

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

I want to bind value of my `mat-slider` to `mat-input`.

I don't need to use `ngModel` for two-way binding because I'm using `formcontrolname`.

my form control names consisted of two parts. first part is fixed  and the other is variable.

here is my html section:

```
      <mat-label>{{relSizFilteredTitle}}</mat-label>
        <h3>Minimum value :</h3>
        <mat-slider
                    invert="false"
                    max="80"
                    min="50"
                    step="1"
                    thumbLabel="true"
                    [(value)]="relSizFilteredTitle + '_min'"
                    tickInterval="true"
                    [formControlName]="relSizFilteredTitle + '_min'"
                    vertical="false">
        </mat-slider>
        <input matInput [formControlName]="relSizFilteredTitle + '_min'"
                   type="number"
                   autocomplete="false"
                   min="50"
                   max="80"
                   required
                   placeholder="">
```

As you can see, I intended to use two way binding with value property. but angular doesn't accept `relSizFilteredTitle + '_min'` as variable name.

you may should know that in the .ts file I have these:

```
  goForward(stepper: MatStepper, operation?: string, element?: any) {
    this.operation = operation;
    stepper.next();
    this.secondFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe(data => this.onSecondFormGroupValueChange(data));

  }

  onSecondFormGroupValueChange(data) {
    // ==> I want to do sth here.
    console.log(data);
  }
```

How do I bind value of mat-slider and mat-input and and vice versa?